# How to use Sed command for quitting lines

Tags: bash, unix, sed

writing a code in which i would download certain images using urls that are stored in certain file and then also keep on assigning the proper names using another file which contains the name of images.

I have tried following code

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=$(cat Final | wc -l)
COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
num=1
while read line
do
if [ $num != $COUNT ]
then
echo $num
name=$(sed '$num q' SourceNameList)
echo $name
wget $line -O /Users/ankit/Downloads/imagesdownloded/$name
num=$(($num+1))
fi
done < imagelinks
```

Faced error for following code :

```
name=$(sed '$num q' SourceNameList)
```

Looking for how to use this particular command of sed using variable

Tried following as well

```
name=$(sed "$numq" SourceNameList)
```

Comment: `name=$(sed "${num} q" File)`? But its not really clear what you're trying to do. (Maybe it doesn't matter). Lots extra code here. Edit your Q to include sample input and expected output, and maybe you'll get a better solution. (Many `awk` people read `sed` Qs. That's what I would recommend). Good luck.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear but I think this is a simple case of using shell variables in sed: `sed "${num}q" SourceNameList` should work, assuming everything else does. You need to use double quotes and the braces prevent the `q` from being interpreted as part of the variable name.

Comment: Thanks tom it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name=$(sed '$num q' SourceNameList)
```

with single quotes, the base variable will *not* be expanded.

```
name=$(sed "$numq" SourceNameList)
```

you're trying to expand a variable named `numq`

You want one of

```
name=$(sed "$num q" SourceNameList)
name=$(sed "${num}q" SourceNameList)
```

However, you don't have to call sed for each line of the imagelinks file: you can read from the 2 files simultaneously

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=$(( $(wc -l < Final) + 1 ))
num=0
while ((++num < COUNT)) && read -u3 line && read -u4 name
do
    echo $num
    echo $name
    wget "$line" -O /Users/ankit/Downloads/imagesdownloded/"$name"
done 3< imagelinks 4< SourceNameList
```

Comment: @Ankit When it works, please accept his answer. Glenn will know that you are really helped and others will not try to answer your question.